# Set navbar menu's class active untill other menu is clicked or until user stays in certain controller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, menuitem

In my project's menubar when certain menu is clicked I set its class to active. This is done with following code

```
public static class MenuExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string text,
    string action,
    string controller
    )
    {
        var li = new TagBuilder("li");
        var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
        var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
            string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            li.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text, action, controller).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
    }
}
```

and this is how I create menubar

```
<ul class="nav-pills">
    //<li> tags class is set to active when clicked
    <li>@Html.MenuItem("Account","Details","Account")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuItem("Contacts","Index","AddressBook")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuItem("SomeMenu","Index","Appointment")</li>
    <li>@Html.MenuItem("Hello "+User.Identity.Name+"!","Manage","Account")</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here, is an example of how **menubar** looks when `Account` menu is clicked
[image]
Now when I click the edit button the orange bar is account menu disappears (class active is removed from menu item). Which is not convinient as user is still in account section.

**Is it possible to set the menu's class active untill another menu is clicked?**
Or 
Until page belongs to certain controller?

For example set menu item' class to active until user stays Account controller (in this case)

Comment: Create sample output, html and js only in jsfiddle.net

Comment: how can I do that? My class are set by first part of code I posted which is more of C# and Html helpers

Comment: just copy and paste output source of your page

Answer (score 0):

removing this part

```
string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

from

```
if (string.Equals(currentAction, action, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    string.Equals(currentController, controller, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    li.AddCssClass("active");
}
```

worked.

It'll not work if your have two menu item that will direct to same controller, in that case both menu item will be wrapped with class active